# How to make circle with break in fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to stop my circle after output first element.

```
<f:for each="{errors}" as="error">
    <f:switch expression="{error.code}">

        <f:comment>The given subject was not a valid email address</f:comment>
        <f:case value="1221559976">
            <f:translate extensionName="helper" key="validator.emailaddress.notvalid" />
        </f:case>

        ...
    </f:switch>

    BREAK????

</f:for>
```

Is it possible with fluid? Regards, Anton

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to iterate the collection, what for? Instead you can just fetch first element like: `{errors.0}`

Additionally if you want to fetch i.e. first 3 elements, you can prepare `$limitedErrors` (or smth) in your PHP controller and then assign it into the view.

It will be still more comfortable than manipulating within the template engine.

Comment: As I've already answered for comment by @vijay-rami it's my temporary solution and it works for this case. But it won't  be working if  we have random index or need to display 2-3 items. Of course we can prepare data in controller or even write custom ViewHelper, but I hoped fluid supports so trivial thing like "break" for circle

Comment: It doesn't for sure, optionally you can override typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/ForViewHelper.php in your own extension and add some param for this i.e.: `limit="3"`, and dynamic limit is important to you that's the way which fits your need best.

Answer (score 1):

You can make you for each loop with additional argument iteration=""

add below code

```
<f:for each="{errors}" as="error" iteration="errorIterator">
```

and add condition

```
<f:if condition="{errorIterator.index} = 0">
```

or

```
<f:if condition="{errorIterator.isFirst}">
```

Comment: My temporary solution is similar: use {errors.0.code} for "f:switch" and remove "f:for" at all. But it won't be working if we have random index or we need to display more than 1 items

Answer (score 0):

May you can use [vhs viewhelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/CaseViewHelper.html)

```
<v:switch value="{variable}">
    <v:case case="someValue" break="TRUE">
        <!-- do whatever, if {variable} == 'someValue' -->
    </v:case>
    <v:case case="default">
        <!-- the case "default" is a reserved keyword which acts as the default case. -->
    </v:case>
</v:switch>
```

> break > boolean

Comment: Thanks for you tip, but I'd like to have "break" for "f:for", not for "f:switch"

Comment: I am not sure, but in Fluid view might not possible to break loop in view. In your case, you have to create your own custom viewhelper for do the stuff.